# AES Encryption (AES/ECB/NoPadding)

Tags: android, ios, encryption, aes

i want to encrypt some data through AES Algorithm.
For iOS i'm using AESCrypt Library and for Android i'm using Cipher Library but i am not the same result although it's the same algorithm we're talking about here. Any Help would be appreciated

iOS Code :

```
NSString *encryptedData = [AESCrypt encrypt:message password:password];
```

Java Code

```
public static String encryptMethod(String seedBase64, byte[] key) {
    try {
        byte[] seed = Base64.decode(seedBase64, 0);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(1, keySpec);
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(seed), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

Comment: i'm pretty sure about the java code because it's giving me the result i need, my problem is with iOS ...

Comment: Yo should definitely use padding, not no padding

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: CommonCrypto supports both ECB and NoPadding through various flags. You don't need some third party library for that, but of course you shouldn't use that code at all. Instead you should use a library that does that for you. Note that good libraries use randomized encryption. So, if you want to check compatibility, you need to encrypt on one side and decrypt on the other.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Never say never, ECB has it's uses. Never say always, authentication kills security if the keyspace is limited (eg PIN-derived key). OP is base64ing, which suggests short, the variable is named `seed`, which suggests random. In case of random, one-block data ECB/NoPadding is **the way** to go.

Comment: @Agent_L Yes, "seed" suggests that it is random, but "base64" doesn't suggest that it is short. "seed" also suggests that it is short, but short is subjective and as the German writer Göthe put it *"Names are sound and smoke"*. Names don't mean much. We don't really know what this is. Yes, there are some cases where ECB is better suited, but it is much easier to suggest a better default which improves 90% of all the code that people are blindly copying from Stack Overflow. Putting it in bold at least encourages people to think.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are issues with the padding on different platforms so the result differs, i would recommend using some cross platform library like this one. https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption

Comment: i used this library and even RNEncryptor and still the result is different from my android code.
Is that normal ?

Comment: The library you're recommending supports multiple languages/platforms, but it lacks one important thing: integrity checking through a message authentication code. RNCryptor is much better in that regard.